# Auto-Detect or Notify when new table created is in Bigquery

Tags: events, google-bigquery, rundeck

Is there any way to auto-detect or notify when a new table is created in bigquery? Based on that I want to trigger a rundeck job.

Comment: Hi @Venugopal Seetharam, you can use [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#metrics) to create alerts. The protoPayload.methodName="tableservice.insert" can be used for your requirement. For more information, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/migration#logs_interface_filters). Let me know if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to utilize event arc and cloud functions v2.  There is actually a pretty decent repository outlining this approach here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/eventarc-samples/tree/main/bigquery-jobs-notifier/gcf

As a note, cloud functions are not the only way, you could also do this via cloud run or other compute options.

Comment: And based on Daniel's answer you can trigger a Rundeck Webhook using functions:  https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/webhooks/run-job.html#run-job-webhook-plugin